# How can I add a button "Remove" when I update the post

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have the poll system to Insert question and edit the question 
so the insert one it's fine just like that

[image]

But I have problems with the update

When I click the edit questions appears to me like that :

[image]

So I want each "add more" to be **close** one , except last one if admin wants to add another field

**the code of form :**

```
@foreach ($choices_name as $loopInput)
<tr>  
  <td><input type="text" value="{{ $loopInput->nameChose }}" name="nameChoose[]" placeholder="Enter the choose" class="form-control name_list"></td>  
  <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

**the of js ::**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i=1;    
    $('#add').click(function(){  
        i++;  
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" name="nameChoose[]" placeholder="Enter the choos" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });  
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loop` of Laravel in your blade :

```
@foreach ($choices_name as $loopInput)
<tr>  
  <td><input type="text" value="{{ $loopInput->nameChose }}" name="nameChoose[]" placeholder="Enter the choose" class="form-control name_list"></td>  
  <td><button type="button" name="close" class="close btn btn-alert">Close</button></td>  
</tr> 
@if($loop->last)
     <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
@endif
@endforeach
```

If you want some Js solution which I'm not sure will work with your case since I dont know how you treat the data afterward you can do something like

```
$('.close').each( () => { 
    $(this).on("click", () => { $(this).parents('.row').remove() })
})
```

Be aware that if you add dynamicaly those close event you will have to target first the parent element so `$('#parentElement .close').each(() => {...})`

Comment: What about the js code ? 
now your code is perfect but ,when I close the input already exist , he doesn't close !

Comment: @rabeea Well this have to be seen from your side I don't know how does work your website if there is some ajax call or anything
If you only want to remove the line then `$(this).parents('.rows').remove()` will do fine